# Exporting HTML PHP webpage to image

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, image-processing

There is a Google map in my site and I need to export that google map to image and need to store. It can be do in any script like PHP or HTML or JAVASCRIPT

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not the place where you just post your request and get people to do your work!

Comment: I think you should read [Google Maps ToS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) for the usage of Google Maps images. Even if, there is no Google-way to export Google Maps to image, and I've don't found any library to do this, you can easily write some functions which permite to draw the maps container in a html canvas. I would not say more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sirko and @Brendan have pointed out, you should provide some kind of code so we have something to work on. But if you are looking for a starting point I would extend on @JBRTRND's suggestion of using html5 canvas to wrap your google maps div in and write some script to convert that to an image. Luckily there is a js library created that accomplishes this task, have a look at this js library and hopefully you will find your answer: http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: Hi I just seen that link you have given above. I think it helps. I will try this.

Comment: Glad it gives you a starting point. An important thing to consider is browser compatibility though. As the link states, html5 Canvases are not supported by IE - so make sure you do a survey of your end-users' browser preferences.